# why php code is not able to upload a image using file and longblob in database?

Tags: php, html

my html code i got

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="image"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD"/>
    </form>
```

my php code i got upload.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false){
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));

        /*
         * Insert image data into database
         */

        //DB details
        $dbHost     = 'localhost';
        $dbUsername = 'root';
        $dbPassword = '';
        $dbName     = 'dictionary';

        //Create connection and select DB
        $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

        // Check connection
        if($db->connect_error){
            die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
        }

        $dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        //Insert image content into database
        $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (image, created) VALUES ('$imgContent', '$dataTime')");
        if($insert){
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";
        }else{
            echo "File upload failed, please try again.";
        } 
    }else{
        echo "Please select an image file to upload.";
    }
}
```

and my database code

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `image` longblob NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

when ever i try to upload an image to database i get response as
**Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\akshayadmin\akshayadmin\upload.php on line 11
Please select an image file to upload.**
 plese do help me with this small error as i am new.

Comment: You can do `$_FILES['image']['size'] ` to get the size instead of that function if you want to give that shot to get rid of that error. Another suggestion, what happens if you `var_dump($_FILES]` ?? your HTML code could be incorrect also. for your input tag use `<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" />` to only accept images.

Comment: Check `$_FILES['image']['error']`. If it's anything other than 0, then an error occurred. If you look in the comment section [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php#115746), you can see what each number means.